# AngularJS select array hash element by name/value

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have the following `angular` array for one of my `select` tags

```
var names= [{name: 'Superman', val: '1'}, {name: 'Batman', val: '2'}];
$scope.names =names;
$scope.FormData = {};
$scope.FormData.name = $scope.names[1];
```

In the above array, instead of selecting the item by index (`1`), how can I select the item by `name` or the `val`, like

```
$scope.FormData.name = $scope.names['2']; #will select the {name: 'Batman', val: '2'}
```

I initially posted a lengthy question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25608805/setting-up-selected-values-for-AngularJS-select), but then I realized this is the more simpler / focus way of my question

Comment: You can use the great Lodash library: http://lodash.com/docs#find

Comment: If you're talking about a select element you should show that too and clarify your question.

Comment: not clear what issue is. Can access the whole object using `ng-options` correctly. Need more details about problem

Comment: What is your issue here? Displaying in the ng-option or selecting the ng-Model data from the array for default selection?

Comment: It seems to be a pure Javascript question, not linked to Angular.

Comment: probably this is an x/y problem which makes it look like a pure javascript question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using `angular`, why not use the build in `$filter`?

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

In your case, if you want to filter in the controller, the code bellow will retrieve an `Array` with all the occurrences inside `names`  that match the search for 'Superman':

```
$filter('filter')($scope.names, {name:'Superman'})
```

If you are confident that there will be at least one match you could do this in order to get the first match:

```
var matches = $filter('filter')($scope.names, {name:'Superman'});
var match = matches[0]:
```

Bare in mind that if there are no matches then `match` will be `undefined`

Answer (score 2):

> In the above array, instead of selecting the item by index (1), how
>   can I select the item by name

You can use the `find` method of the **Lodash** library (http://lodash.com/docs#find):

```
var names= [{name: 'Superman', val: '1'}, {name: 'Batman', val: '2'}];

var matchingBatman = _.find(names, { name: 'Batman' });
```

`matchingBatman` is:  `{name: 'Batman', val: '2'}`

You can do the same if you want to find by `val`:

```
var matchingBatman = _.find(names, { val: '2' });
```

Comment: thanks for answer, I liked the idea of $filter as it seems more `angular`, but this will be a library I will surly look in to

Comment: @sameera207 Yes, the solution with $filter is equivalent, so make use of it. Lodash is useful for many complex manipulations of arrays/collections, I'm using it a lot :)

Comment: I'm pretty new to `angular` and I think its just mater of days/hours I need to start using `Lodash` :)

Comment: Everytime you'll need to manipulate arrays/collections, look at what Angular has, and if it hasn't a pretty way to do what you exactly want, Lodash is likely to be the key.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a re-useable function you could do it like this:

```
$scope.find = function(list, attributeName, attributeValue){
    var returnVal = {};
    angular.forEach(list,function(item){
        if(item[attributeName]){
          if(item[attributeName] === attributeValue){
            returnVal = item;
          }
        }
    });
    return returnVal;
};

$scope.FormData.name = $scope.find(names,'name','Batman');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a function instead of using a library

```
function selectByProperty(key, val){

    for(var i=0; i< $scope.names.length; i++){
        if($scope.names[i][key] === val){
           return $scope.names[i];
         }
     }

}
$scope.FormData.name  = selectByProperty('val','2');
```

Comment: Why would you want to iterate once you have found a match

Comment: thanks for answer, I liked the idea of $filter as it seems more `angular`